# Combine three tables and display their status (only recent entries for shared fields) in an oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables that I want to combine. For this I wrote a query, but the problem is that I have achieved my goal partially. I want to make a table with the status of filling! for this I need the data from the table SEC_OBJECTS_FILLING to be constant and the data from the other tables to be the latest!

I modeled the script (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72de71f849e103d3462137248f90e60a) and
I have a result there. But I want to have a result like this.

```
NAME_OBJ  DATA_AREA   SEALS  DATA        NAME_UR  SEAL_NUMBER  NAME_USR  DATA_UNPLUG
--------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------- ----------- ---------- -----------
OBJ1      DATA_AREA1  Yes     2019-11-13  ADMIN    A14602631    
OBJ2      DATA_AREA2  Yes     2019-11-13  ANDRII   A14602632
OBJ3      DATA_AREA1  No      2019-11-13  ADMIN    A14602638    ADMIN     2019-11-13 
OBJ4      DATA_AREA1  No
```

That is, I only want to see the latest activity with my object, not the whole story.
(I sealed objects (1,2,3,) and sealed objects (1,2,3), but then sealed objects (1,2) again. Object 4 I did not seal!) I hope you understand.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: I am baffled by what your question is.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation *in this question* are all helpful.  Your specified results, for instance, have "OBJ4", but that is not in your data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I covered the old link, I'm already correcting, sorry  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9cc1b8152f0e9bba279c5cd3503d6766

Answer (score 0):

Does below query fulfill your goal -

```
SELECT NAME_OBJ, DATA_AREA, SEALS, DATA, NAME_UR,
       SEAL_NUMBER, NAME_USR, DATA_UNPLUG
  FROM
  (
   SELECT sof.NAME_OBJ, sof.DATA_AREA, sof.SEALS, sos.DATA, sos.NAME_UR,
          sos.SEAL_NUMBER, sou.NAME_USR, sou.DATA_UNPLUG,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sof.NAME_OBJ ORDER BY sos.SEAL_NUMBER) as rnk
     FROM SEC_OBJECTS_FILLING sof
     LEFT JOIN SEC_OBJECT_SEALING sos 
       ON sof.NAME_OBJ = sos.SEALING_OBJECT 
      AND sof.DATA_AREA = sos.DATA_AREA
     LEFT JOIN SEC_OBJECT_UNPLUG sou
       ON sou.OBJECT_UNPLUG = sos.SEALING_OBJECT 
      AND sos.DATA_AREA = sou.DATA_AREA 
      AND sou.SEAL_NUMBER = sos.SEAL_NUMBER
   )
  WHERE rnk = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd9b5f5143d07c8e207e3cb1a5a35f9a) is the demo.

Comment: Thank you, but in the question, I indicated what my answer should look like)))

Comment: I have a demo! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b5b2ce2e0108c2f34b0c3dab30c0579f  , you can make the answer from my demo that I described in the question!? _))) I just can not understand (

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak, I have updated my answer as per updated fiddle. However the assignment of SEAL NUMBER is still matching with your expected result. May you plesae check that your expected result must be exactly same as you mentioned in question like there is no A14602638 in sample data but it is there in your question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc936dd6739e6d9418ae465dcbbd2a5e  you can look at the demo), this is the same situation in me with real data !! Object 1 was sealed to me 3 times and 2 times ((the last time 06.12.2019 and after that it was not sealed) and in our request it is written sho it was sealed, although the last action with it was when it was sealed

Comment: can you help me in this ??

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak, Its not possible to identify that the OBJ 1 was not sealed at last coz you have only 1 entry as YES only. So I guess you need to modify your sample data a bit and your problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

An analytic function need to filter out those data such as `RANK()`,

which has `PARTITION BY NAME_OBJ` clause in order to group the ranking results by each object names,

and apply `ORDER BY SEAL_NUMBER DESC` with **descending** option to be able to get the recent entries by **seal numbers** for each **object names** :

```
SELECT NAME_OBJ, DATA_AREA, SEALS, DATA, NAME_UR,
       SEAL_NUMBER, NAME_USR, DATA_UNPLUG
  FROM
  (
   SELECT sof.NAME_OBJ, sof.DATA_AREA, sof.SEALS, sos.DATA, sos.NAME_UR,
          sos.SEAL_NUMBER, sou.NAME_USR, sou.DATA_UNPLUG,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sof.NAME_OBJ ORDER BY sos.SEAL_NUMBER DESC) as rnk
     FROM SEC_OBJECTS_FILLING sof
     LEFT JOIN SEC_OBJECT_SEALING sos 
       ON sof.NAME_OBJ = sos.SEALING_OBJECT 
      AND sof.DATA_AREA = sos.DATA_AREA
     LEFT JOIN SEC_OBJECT_UNPLUG sou
       ON sou.OBJECT_UNPLUG = sos.SEALING_OBJECT 
      AND sos.DATA_AREA = sou.DATA_AREA 
      AND sou.SEAL_NUMBER = sos.SEAL_NUMBER
   )
  WHERE rnk = 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d992ba57065ba21eac241aa7b9301b9)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is almost what I need, but when I threw in a clean version with real data, I got an error !!!! But there in some objects tightening not the last seals on the object !! What can be a problem ??? maybe the problem is because I indicated in the demo that in the SEC_OBJECT_SEALING column the DATA column is a varchar type, but in fact there is a date type!

Comment: I thought maybe use "fetch first 1 row only;" but did not understand how to insert it in this request!

Comment: I want to explain in more detail the problem after using your request! Most sites are fine, but I have objects that have been sealed, sealed, but then sealed again !! but the status does not show that it has been sealed again, and the date of filling is penultimate, not the last! Although the status of "SEALS" is displayed correctly !! I am very grateful for your help! Can we have a chat (if you have the time and the desire to help me) to tell you more about this situation

Comment: hi @AndriiHavrylyak, now I'm available, you're welcome. What's your DB version ? Is the value for `seal_number` unique and non-null?

Comment: version 18c, so the seal number is unique and not zero for tables of SEC_OBJECT_SEALING and SEC_OBJECT_UNPLUG!!I have a UNPLUG table filled in with the form, and the values ​​of the fill number in the form can only be from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING, that is, I can only fill in the object that was sealed

Comment: then, you can also use fetch ... clause as being version 12c+ @AndriiHavrylyak and there should be no problem because you're using `seal_number` column of `SOS` table with `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: I did not give enough information in the example.  When filling the object, I fill out the form.  In the form, I select an object from the popup list of available objects, select a seal and automatically enter the data area, user, and time!  That's it!  And after that my status of filling in the FILLING table changes, the column automatically changes the status in the SEALS column!  And when sealed, the status changes!

Comment: Try to add `WHERE sos.SEAL_NUMBER is not null` at the bottom part of the subquery @AndriiHavrylyak .

Comment: it didn't help, it only hid those objects that have never been sealed before!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203844/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-andrii-havrylyak).

Comment: and it is possible to add to the request, the conditions, if there is a seal number from the second table, then it should be the latest by the date of filling

Comment: Hi again))) i found what was the problem! dbfiddle.uk/…  
The demo has an example, the whole problem in the sequence of fillings !!! I have a set of seals for sealing (from A14602600 to A14602650) in the demo we sealed the seals sequentially, everything worked perfectly for you, but in reality, the seals can not be selected consistently and I just dropped you demo in which it was demonstrated !!